# Android Google Map Cluster icon ignores custom icon

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Android Google Map Cluster icon ignores custom icon on zoom out. Any suggestion how to fix it?

```
override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<T>, markerOptions: MarkerOptions) {
    mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(context?.let { ContextCompat.getDrawable(it, R.drawable.map_cluster_item) })
    mClusterIconGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.WhiteTextAppearance)
    val icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(cluster.size.toString())
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed with override of `getDescriptorForCluster`

```
private val mClusterIconGenerator = IconGenerator(context).apply {
    setBackground(context?.let { ContextCompat.getDrawable(it, R.drawable.map_cluster_item) })
    setTextAppearance(R.style.WhiteTextAppearance)
}
override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<T>, markerOptions: MarkerOptions) {
    val icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(cluster.size.toString())
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
}
override fun getDescriptorForCluster(cluster: Cluster<T>): BitmapDescriptor {
    val icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(cluster.size.toString())
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)
}
```